# How to add "Check all" to Edit post page in WP?

Tags: wordpress

I want to add a checkbox to Edit Post page in Wordpress admin and clicking on that checkbox should select all categories

How can I do that?

Image description bellow...

[image]

Comment: You should also ask on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to think of a way to help you out and came with the following solution. What I basically did was make an extra script and enqueue this one in the backend.

Make a file called be-scripts.js and place it in "theme_folder/js/". Put the following code into it:

```
(function($) {

  // Select all categories
  $('#categorychecklist').prepend('<li class="popular-category" id="category-all"><label class="selectit"><input type="checkbox" class="checkall" id="in-category-all" name="post_category[]"> Check all</label></li>');

  $('.checkall').click(function () {
    $(this).parents('ul:eq(0)').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Next you need to enqueue this script into the backend of your site. You can do this by going into your theme folder and open functions.php. Add the following code to it:

```
function init_be_javascripts() {
    if (is_admin()) {
        wp_register_script('extra_be-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/be-scripts.js', 'jquery', 0.1, true );
        wp_enqueue_script('extra_be-script');
    }
}    
add_action('init', 'init_be_javascripts');
```

If all went well you can select "Check all" when editing a post.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks @ravi